# How to show discrete measure $\mu$ is an additive set function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

suppose on a set X,

$\{p_{j}, j \geq 1\} \subseteq X$, $j \in \mathbb{N} $ denoted as a set of distinct points.

$\{a_{j}, j \geq 1\}$ $j \in \mathbb{N}$ denoted as a sequence of real numbers.

$C \subseteq P(X)$,

then Discrete Measure is defined as: $\forall A \in C: \mu(A)= \sum_{j \geq1} a_{j}*1\{p_{j}\in A\}$.

Hence $\mu$ is an additive set function.

It is easy to check $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, such as When $A=\emptyset$, then $p_{j} \notin \emptyset $,  $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}$, Hence $\mu(A) = 0$,

However, I am having trouble to check the second condition for $\mu$ being additive,  Suppose we have a sequence of disjoint ${E_{i}},i \in \mathbb{N}, E_{i} \in C$, and $\cup_{i\geq1}E_{i} \in C$, then $\mu(\cup_{i \geq 1}E_{i})$ = $\sum_{i\geq 1}\sum_{j\geq 1} a_{j} * 1 \{{p_j} \in E_{i}\}$. Is this enough? I think I have missed something, because I have just stated what the second condition is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can always interchange the order of summation when the terms are non-negative. Hence $ \sum_i \mu (E_i)=\sum_i \sum_j a_j I_{\{p_j \in E_i\}} =\sum_j \sum_i a_j I_{\{p_j \in E_i\}}=\sum_j  a_j I_{\{p_j \in \cup_i E_i\}} =\mu (\cup_i E_i)$. [$\sum_i  I_{\{p_j \in E_i\}}=  I_{\{p_j \in \cup_i E_i\}}$ because of disjointness].

Comment: Thank you! @KaviRamaMurthy. I should ve stated 'only for non-negative real numbers' in the question, and I have just rephrased your answers a bit.  since $\forall A \in C: \mu(A)= \sum_{j \geq1} a_{j}*1\{p_{j}\in A\}$.  and $\cup E_{i} \in C $, Then $\mu(\cup E_{i})= \sum_{j \geq1} a_{j}*1\{p_{j}\in \cup_{i}E_{i} \}$, Then $\mu(\cup E_{i})= \sum_{i} \sum_{j} a_{j}*1\{p_{j}\in  E_{i} \}$, Hence $\mu(\cup E_{i})=\sum_{i} \mu(E_{i})$.